# Is it possible to display an Angular Material datepicker without the associated input?

Tags: angular-material

[Angular Material's datepicker](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker) is exactly what I need except that I don't want the selected date displayed in an input. Is there a simple button version of the control that I can use instead?

I would like to use the datepicker to select a month (similar to Google Calendar shown below).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to select months, it may be better to use `md-select`. If you want to remove the input of `md-datepicker` you could use CSS. As far as I know it is not possible to make `md-datepicker` just select months.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/qaWayO)

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  Month selector:
  <br>
  <md-input-container style="margin-right: 10px;">
    <label>Month</label>
    <md-select ng-model="month">
      <md-option ng-repeat="month in months" value="{{month}}">{{month}}</md-option>
    </md-select>
  </md-input-container>
  <br>
  Selected month: {{month}}
  <br>
  <md-divider></md-divider>
  <br>
  Date picker with no input :
  <br>
  <md-datepicker id="myDatePicker" ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.months = [
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December"
  ];
});
```

CSS

```
#myDatePicker .md-datepicker-input-container,
#myDatePicker .md-datepicker-input-container input,
#myDatePicker .md-datepicker-input-container button {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```